# unable to start the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, webrick

When I try to start my rails server i get this error

```
   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby  /gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.8/mysql 2.so: 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.  
 - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 /gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.8/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

Tried changing the libmysql.dll file even then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with mysql. It is a 64 bit installation. Change it to 32bit and it runs fine.